Why does the Android Studio emulator screen appear then disappear and only appear in the taskbar?
When I run the emulator, it suddenly appears, then disappears and appears in the tool bars. When the mouse pointer passes, it only appears in the tool bars, as it can be seen here:

I tried to delete the emulator several times and updated the packages but to no avail.


There is be a tab called Running devices on the right side bottom of the Android studio in the tools section. Click on that and you'll be able to see the running device.

if its not visible,

Go to view -> Tool Windows -> Running devices
You will be able to view the emulator if its running,  in a small window.
You'll be able to resize it / undock it.


